# How to reduce memory use of fitted sklearn estimators

Tags: python, memory, scikit-learn

I am fitting and persisting a bunch of scikit-learn models, which subsequently I need to deploy to production servers.

The joblib pickle object for some of the generated models (mostly for bagged estimators) takes a lot of space, in the order of 50MB (note that this is *compressed* data).

The memory consumption of these models is limiting how many different ones I can upload to a single production server.

For our workflow, fitting happens in our development machines (with plenty of cores and memory), but production runs in a tighter environment. Since once we deploy a model we are not interested in fitting anymore, just on predicting, I was wondering if I could prune the python object before persisting it, things like the features used for fitting (assuming they are not needed in the `predict` step).

So, the question is: is there an easy way of identifying elements of a fitted sklearn estimator that are not needed for calling the `predict` method and removing them from the class prior to persisting the object?

**Additional clarifications**

I am not concerned about disk space, just about system memory use; determining the amount of memory used by a single one is tricky so I used the pickled size as a proxy (in-memory size ranges around 3-7x the size of the pickle). The estimators that get uploaded to the production system can in principle be anything (we are building a Caruana-type ensemble out of them). The worst offenders are instances of `MLPClassifier` or `RandomForestClassifier`. Issue seems to be that for an estimator of a fixed "size" (say I fix the number of inputs and hidden layer neurons for a network) the size of the saved estimator seems to grow depending on the dataset I use to train it, which to me looks like some of the training data is being kept inside the instance object. Training data is not needed for a neural network or a random forest to make a prediction, so I would like to get rid of it if it is there.

Comment: I see at least two questions and i'm not sure what you are really after. The one is targeting disk-space consumption, the other one is targeting system-memory (there is not always a 1:1 mapping depending on the classifier in use). There is not much you can throw away from your estimators. Maybe some simple stats are saved, but most of the input is needed for prediction. If that's too big for your case, your are using the wrong classifiers.

Comment: You should explain more about your estimators.